# how to accelerate custom function using GPU/MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, gpu

suppose I got an function *f(x)* ,s.t . *yi=f(xi)*

now an array=(x1,x2,……,xn) is given,we want to compute z = f(array),
how to accelerate the computation using GPU?

i.e, the code didn't reflect the parallel acceleration capability of gpu

```
shape = 40;
shapez = 100000;
b = gpuArray(single(ones(shape,shape,shapez)));
for i=1:shapez
    c =mean(b(:,:,i));
end
disp(['gpu processing time: ', num2str(toc(t1)), ' seconds']);
```

If I change the code as follows,It becomes much faster.

```
t1 = tic;
shape = 40;
shapez = 100000;
b = gpuArray(single(ones(shape,shape,shapez)));

disp(['gpu processing time: ', num2str(toc(t1)), ' seconds']);
```

So,if the basic logic of my algorithm is as follows,how to implement it so that it could be accelated by GPU?：

```
for i=1:length(array)
    yi = f(xi)
end
```

Comment: There is no way to accelerate any arbitrary function `f`. GPU code is highly function specific, so general solutions simply do not exist. in your case, MATLAB comes with 2 implementations if `mean`, one for CPU and one for GPU, thats why it works. You want to accelerate your function, you are going to need to write it yourself in CUDA, and use the mex interface, no "easy cheat" around

Comment: Also, your first case is slow because you are running too little computations on the GPU. it takes time to start the gpu, put memory there, and take it out. If you only use 40x40 matrices, the startup and stopping of the GPU will be all the time. if you are not doing big computations at the same time, it won't be faster to do GPU computing

Comment: alright, There ain't no such thing as a free lunch. Are there any tutorials for CUDA /MATLAB？Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

To use pre-existing Matlab GPU-accelerated functions, you can find them listed [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/referencelist.html?type=function&capability=gpuarrays)

If you want to implement your own functions, you can use MEX as described [here](https://es.mathworks.com/help/parallel-computing/accessing-advanced-cuda-features-using-mex.html) in their official documentation.